# Find Duplicate Multidimensional Array and remove from array php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

How to remove multi dimensional array if duplicate. 
   In this example Barcode is duplicate value of 111 i want to remove this if found duplicate. PLease help Im new to php. Thanks

Output:

```
 Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Barcode] => 111
        [Transaction_No] => 256
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Barcode] => 111
        [Transaction_No] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Barcode] => 222
        [Transaction_No] => 0
    )

)
```

Expected Output:

```
 Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Barcode] => 222
        [Transaction_No] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: You want to remove duplicate value / both same value?

Comment: What I want is to remove this array 2 array.  Actually its dynamic meaning when found barcode duplicate remove all duplicate

Comment: Means you want to remove same barcode value array right?

Comment: Yes Correct  Nikhil Vaghla. if all are the same then remove all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This keeps track of the keys of each barcode array item to find duplicates, then uses array_values at the end to fix the array indexing.

```
<?php
$myArray = array(
    array
    (
        "Barcode" => 111,
        "Transaction_No" => 256
    ),
    array
    (
        "Barcode" => 111,
        "Transaction_No" => 0
    ),
    array
    (
        "Barcode" => 222,
        "Transaction_No" => 0
    )
);

$barcodeKeys = array();
foreach ($myArray as $key => $arr) {
    $code = $arr["Barcode"];
    if (!isset($barcodeKeys[$code])) {
        $barcodeKeys[$code] = array();
    }

    $barcodeKeys[$code][] = $key;

    if (count($barcodeKeys[$code]) > 1) {
        foreach ($barcodeKeys[$code] as $dupKey) {
            if (isset($myArray[$dupKey])) {
                unset($myArray[$dupKey]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$myArray = array_values($myArray);
print_r($myArray);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Barcode] => 222
            [Transaction_No] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Woah! Thanks  ebildude123 expected output correct. Thanks a lot you save my day! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fast approach to your question:

```
<?php
$barcodes =  array(array( 'Barcode' => 111,'Transaction_No' => 256),array('Barcode' => 111,'Transaction_No' => 0),array('Barcode' => 222,'Transaction_No' => 0),array('Barcode' => 333,'Transaction_No' => 0)); 
$result = array();
$exist = array();
foreach($barcodes as $key => $item){
    if( in_array( $item['Barcode'], array_values( $exixt ) ){
         unset( $result[ array_search ( $item['Barcode'], $exist ) ] );
    } else {
        $result[ $key ] = array('Barcode' => $item['Barcode'],'Transaction_No' => $item['Transaction_No'] );
        $exist[ $item['Barcode'] ] = $key;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Where did you get the $barcode variable? it does not work

Comment: Hi  xAqweRx thanks for the code. ebildude123 code is much near to my expectation. Anyway thanks for suggestion